# DB2 Transaction Logs - can they be COPY-PASTE on another Disaster Recovery Server?

Tags: db2, transaction-log, logs, snapshot, disaster-recovery

We have Server1 with Online Backup1, Archive Logs 1,2,3 for example and Transaction Logs from  1 to 10.
We are interested in next scenario:
If Server1 fails completely and we want to move everything on second server I suppose it is not the problem to move and restore Backup1 and Archive logs 1,2,3 on Server2.
But can Transaction Logs (their snapshot in some specific time) be also copied to the Server2? Because Transaction Logs are probably the most problematic part for this Disaster Recovery Scenario. Can there be some problem with the fact that transaction logs are written and populated all the time?

ADDITION: DISK option is used when configuring Archive Mode

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you wish to look into HADR on DB2. It actually does log shipping to the standby, so if there is a fail over you can either manually take over on the standby, or if you install TSA (Tivoli Systems Automation), then you can have it detect a failure and automatically fail over to the standby.

If you don't want HADR, then yes, you could copy logs. Or even use the alternate/mirror log/archive parameters to get DB2 to copy the logs (possibly to a shared mount).

Comment: Hi Chris, no we are interested when Archive Mode is set with DISK option (unfortunately must be DISK because that is the requirement from the Customer). Please tell me if this is something which is possible or not? I am also confused little with the question from the customer but that is what they are asking us (I am aware that transaction logs are "active", database is populating them actively ) but please tell me if this is feasible or not? So we would copy ALL (online backup+archive logs+transaction logs) on another Disaster Recovery Server

Comment: Chris please tell us if this is feasible  without HADR feature and TSA (I am familiar with that we implemented it for other customer but this customer does not want this option)

Comment: I know of TSA, but have not implemented HADR with it. Read up on Ember Crooks blog (db2commerce.com) for information on that.

Comment: If you dont' want HADR, then yes, you could copy logs. Or even use the alternate/mirror log/archive parameters to get DB2 to copy  the logs (possibly to a shared mount).

Comment: Hi Chris, OK so you think this is OK. I am just concerned if database will know in which of those copied transaction logs it should write data into for the next transactions.

Comment: If you are speaking of HADR, generally speaking....it won't. It will read the logs and commit them to disk. It will only create its own logs if it becomes the primary.